# How to define an arbitrary discrete probability distribution with a list of mass without warnings

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

In Mathematica 8, I want to define a discrete distribution with density mass given as a list.  For example,

```
In[1] f = ProbabilityDistribution[{2/3, 1/3}[[x]], {x, 1, 2, 1}];
```

This seems to work.  However, this emitted a twice-repeated warning:

```
"Part::pspec: Part specification x is neither an integer nor a list of integers."
```

Nevertheless, f seems to work correctly.  This message got me thinking that there may be a better way to define the same distribution.  How can I define a discrete distribution using a list but without invoking the warning?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Could convert the list of weights to a Piecewise, and feed that to ProbabilityDistribution.

```
wts = {2/3, 1/3};
toPiecewise[wts_, x_] := 
 Piecewise[MapIndexed[{#1, x == #2[[1]]} &, wts]]

In[178]:= f = 
 ProbabilityDistribution[toPiecewise[wts, x], {x, 1, 2, 1}]

Out[178]= ProbabilityDistribution[
 Piecewise[{{2/3, \[FormalX] == 1}, {1/3, \[FormalX] == 2}}, 0], 
   {\[FormalX], 1, 2, 1}]
```

Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It works, and I learned a new function MapIndexed!

Answer (score 17):

You may want to use `EmpiricalDistribution` when constructing a distribution from a list of values:

```
empiricalDistribution = EmpiricalDistribution[{2/3, 1/3} -> {1, 2}]
```

and you can then use this in other statistical and visualization functions:

```
Plot[CDF[empiricalDistribution][x], {x, 0, 4}]
```

The function `ProbabilityDistribution` is more appropriate when you have a *pdf*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I tried this, and it indeed worked!  I wish I was able to accept both Daniel's and your answers.

Comment: Yes, both answers provide great information about building a discrete distribution